# Working with Locales in Swing (with change at runtime)?

Tags: java, swing, localization

I thought about the best way to implement localisation with runtime  in Swing.

I currently solve the problem like that:

```
JMenu menuData = new JMenu("Data");
    menuData.setName("mainframe.menu.data"); // property key
    localeChangedListener.add(menuData);
```

The `LocaleChangedListener`:

```
public class SwingLocaleChangedListener implements LocaleChangedListener {

    private ArrayList<AbstractButton>   abstractButtons;

    @Override
    public void localeChanged(ResourceBundle rb) {
        logger.info("Locale changed to '" + rb.getLocale() + "'");
        for (AbstractButton b : abstractButtons) {
            b.setText(rb.getString(b.getName()));
            b.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.getOrientation(rb.getLocale())); //EDIT: Line added
        }

    }

    public boolean add(AbstractButton b) {
        initAbstractButtons();
        return abstractButtons.add(b);
    }

    private void initAbstractButtons() {
        if (abstractButtons == null) {
            this.abstractButtons = new ArrayList<AbstractButton>();
        }
    }
}
```

And the registration of the `Listener`:

```
public class GuiBundleManager {

    private String                  filePrefix  = "language.lang";
    private ResourceBundle          rb         = null;
    private LocaleChangedListener   listener    = null;

    private static GuiBundleManager instance    = null;

    private GuiBundleManager() { 
        setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    }

    public String getString(String key) {
        return rb.getString(key);
    }

    public String[] getStringArray(String key) {
        return rb.getStringArray(key);
    }

    public Locale getLocale() {
        return rb.getLocale();
    }

    public void setLocale(Locale l) {
        rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle(filePrefix, l);
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.localeChanged(rb);
        }
    }

    public LocaleChangedListener getLocaleChangedListener() {
        return listener;
    }

    public void setLocaleChangedListener(LocaleChangedListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.localeChanged(rb);
        }
    }

    public static GuiBundleManager get() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new GuiBundleManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Another way I'm thinking of is using `Component.setLocale()` combined with an `PropertyChangedListener`:

```
public abstract class GUIComponentFactory {

    public JLabel createLocalisedJLabel(final String key) {
        final JLabel label = new JLabel(GuiBundleManager.get().getString(key));
        label.addPropertyChangeListener("locale", new PropertyChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
                label.setText(GuiBundleManager.get().getString(key));
                label.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.getOrientation(e.getNewValue())); //Edit: Line added
                for(Component c : getComponents()){
                    c.setLocale(e.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        });
                return label;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider [`applyComponentOrientation()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#applyComponentOrientation%28java.awt.ComponentOrientation%29), which recursively "Sets the `ComponentOrientation` property of this component and all components contained within it." Examples may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475320).

Comment: I think I'll implement the PropertyChangedListener structure. This way seems more flexible to me

Comment: Agree; it's included in every `Component`. Do you have any `i18n` plans?

Comment: I have a method in GuiBundleManager that list all locates with existing properties File (and you can change at runtime) - is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes; skimmed right past it! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Whatever approach you finally decide upon: you don't have to handle the resourceBundles yourself. Instead, add them to the UIManager and query that for the localized values:

```
// edited: it's the defaults which take the bundle, my bad I didn't check core api
// SwingX has a UIManagerExt which takes it directly :-)
UIManager.getDefaults().addResourceBundle("com.xypackage.resources.MyBundle");
...
label.setText(UIManager.get(key, label.getLocale());
```

There used to be (didn't check if it's fixed) a bug which prevented this to work reliably in webstartables.

Comment: UIManager.addResourceBundle() does not exist in my Java version (1.7) |||| but UIManager.getDefaults().addResourceBundle(bundleName) does

Comment: And this is also a problem: public Object get(Object key, Locale l) {
        Object value = getFromHashtable( key );
        return (value != null) ? value : getFromResourceBundle(key, l);
    }

Comment: this means that it only returns the message of the first .properties and ignores the given Locale

Comment: darn, you are right with your first comment (will edit). Don't understand your conclusion: the lookup will return the most fitting value for the given locale, falling down from the most specific to the base.

Comment: UIManager.get(key, Locale.GERMAN) and UIManager.get(key, Locale.ENGLISH) return the same value (the German one)

Comment: do you have a _en properties file (assuming your default locale is German)? If not, you have to add it: the "second-last-resort" fallback is the default locale's property, not the base. For a complete description, see ResourceBundle.get(..). If you have one, something else goes wrong, the lookup in the UIManager should work (haha, optimistic me :-) Best show a SSCCE so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: the problem was that my .propertis had names like 'lang_de_DE.properties' and I used Loclale.GERMAN. I changed the filenames to 'lang_de.properties' and now it works